# Deploy the default MVC 4 template to windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am very new to Windows Azure and am tinkering with it to learn how it works. To keep things as simple as possible, I am trying to deploy the default MVC 4 template that is generated by VS 2012 Express for web. I created a new project - an  Azure cloud service. I selected an MVC 4 web role. And that creates a nice little asp.net application with home, about and contact pages, and links to register and login. I just want to deploy this site to Azure and see it work on the cloud.

However the membership does not appear to work on azure. The pages of the application appear correct. However when I click the 'Register' link it does not take me to a page to nter a new username and password. I do not believe the membership tables are being generated anywhere either.

Considering how simple this is, I think I must be making a silly mistake somewhere. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Also, for the record, I have noticed that if I create a stand alone MVC 4 project in VS2012 Express (as opposed to a Windows Azure Cloud service project with an mvc 4 web role) then when I right click that MVC4 project and choose to publish it, it allows me to specify a sql database using a connection string. What is more is once it is published to Azure, the membership works perfectly. I can create useraccounts and log in. If I examine my SQL Azure database using the azure portal, I can see the new membership tables created there.

But when I try to publish a  Windows Azure Cloud service with MVC4 webrole, I do not see any option to provide a connection string of any sort to the azure project. Maybe that is why the membership is not working... since there is no database linked with the web role... but I cannot figure out how to specify this. I was under the impression that publishing a stand alone MVC4 project to Azure, and publishing an Azure Cloud Service with an MVC4 Web Role is the exact same thing, please correct me if I am wrong. And either way, I should be able to see the membership functionality of my mvc 4 web role.

Here are the steps to recreate what I have. Basically it is all default stuff:

1. Create a new project in VS2012 Express 
   File -> New Project -> 'Windows Azure Cloud Service'.
2. On the next screen add an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Role to it.
3. On the subsequent screen choose 'Internet Application'.

These 3 steps create a new project. It runs locally just fine.
Now I try to put it on the cloud.

1. Right click on the windows azure project in solution explorer and choose 'Publish'.
2. Choose the subscription (I already have certificate/credentials in place to publish to azure from VS so I select that)
3. Create a cloud service on the next screen (I name it 'garyazurecloudservice').
4. Accept all the default settings in the Publish wizard and click Publish.

The publishing process takes a few minutes. 
The web application can be viewed at http://garyazurecloudservice.cloudapp.net/.

The Home, About and Contact pages all display correctly. However it I click the 'Register' link at the top right I see a webpage with the correct layout template, but an error in red that says: 
"Error. An error occurred while processing your request."

I have tried to create an SQL database on Azure but I don't see any way to connect this role to it. Possibly that is the problem? Or maybe it is something else altogether. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what is wrong.

I have spent the entire day googling and going in circles with no success. Thank you for any help you can provide. 
Gary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in that the Membership section of your website would not be able to create the SQL tables in the background when running on Azure, due only the problem of where those tables would reside.

Remember, that Azure hosting space is different from traditional hosting, in that your site would exist on a virtual machine, with files being replicated to another virtual machine if the first were to experience problems.  Also, what would happen if you were to invoke a second 'server' to host your website, to cater for a load, perhaps? Where would the tables live then, and how would the second virtual machine know how to access the first?

The answer would be to create a SQL Azure database, upload your tables there, and then you'd have a permanent place for 1, 2 or 1000 'servers' that are running your website to access a central database repository of your data.

I know in your example, it should just 'work' and I agree to some extent, but your application running on your local machine or with your existing (traditional) web host is quite different to the Azure model of working.

In terms of your question regarding how the SQL Azure set-up works, presumably you've created this through the Portal, via the www.windowsazure.com website?  If so, then you should be able to see and manage your SQL Azure database from there, including gaining access to the Connection Strings section, whereby you would copy and paste these into your web.config file for your MVC4 application.  From there, you can utilise this database pretty much as though you would any other.

I hope this all helps - Azure is a beautiful beast once tamed.

Comment: additional info http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/20/new-tutorial-series-and-sample-application-for-asp-net-mvc-4-with-windows-azure-tables-blobs-and-queues.aspx

Comment: Brett,

Thanks for your reply and for pointing out the bigger picture in Azure. The problem here was with the connection string alone. I had previously tried to set the connection string in web.config to point to the sql azure database, but I think I did it incorrectly. This time I copied and pasted it from the connection strings section on the azure portal as you recommended and now it works perfectly! Registration/login works, and I see all the membership and roles tables being automatically generated by mvc4.

Thank you again for your help. 
Gary